# Connecting a USB to mSATA

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, usb

I have recently purchased the Raspberry Pi Desktop kit which has an mSATA interface... However, as SSD's are quite expensive these days and it only operates with USB 2.0 speeds, it occured to me I'd be much better off just to use a USB.
I could just use a USB in another one of the USB ports, but I don't want to waste a USB port. I had an idea, which might be stupid, but is there anyway I could connect a USB to an mSATA interface? I tried lookin for a USB female to mSATA male but had no success.
Any information would be gratefully accepted

Comment: No, the opposite...

Answer (score 1):

You are already using a USB port!

The desktop kit has a mSata Connection that connects to the USB port of the pi. It comes with a little dongle that connects the mini usb port of the mSata adapter to the full size usb port of the pi.
You are asking to accomplish this    Rpi(USB)--->mSATA--->(USB Drive)
Which there is no need. You can boot directly from a USB drive

If you need more usb ports you can use a hub

Comment: Yeah, that's my point.... RPI 3 has 4 USB ports. I have my keyboard in one, my mouse in another, my externally powered USB hub, and the rpi desktop. Preferably I want to keep my USB hub clean and empty on my desk, with nothing plugged into it, however if i wanted to just boot from a USB drive I'd have to move something from the pi to the hub. (Don't say buy another hub). USB--->mSATA---->USB is exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Well if you don't want the mSATA Drive to be used, you don't have to use that little dongle. Then that port can be used for a flash drive.   The usb pass through dongle is only for the drive. The rest of the functionality of the piDesktop board goes through the GPIO pins.

Comment: I have the same pi desktop kit and I was not able to get their mSATA adapter to work (doesnt mean it wont, I didnt spend a lot of time on it.) and I am using an external usb---> mSATA adapter to my SSD.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this link at rasperrypi.org will shed a little light on the Pi USB.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/usb/README.md

Basically keep in mind the Ethernet and usb are controlled by the same chip that juggles these bottlenecking  speeds of these connected devices. You can make a desktop from an RPi, but might be limited, where similar SoC Pi like devices might be geared for higher bus speeds and network bandwidth, but might be more costly than a simple raspberry pi.